# How to traverse a 35 millions of rows table - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, bigdata

I have a really large mysql table which stores domains and subdomains. And its create syntax like below

```
CREATE TABLE `domain` (
  `domain_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `dn` (`domain_name`),
  KEY `ind_domain_name` (`domain_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=78364364 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci;
```

and it stores values like

```
domain_id | domain_name

1         | a.example.com

2         | b.example.com 

3         | example.com

4         | facebook.com

5         | a.facebook.com

6         | google.com
```

I want to find subdomains of any top domain and then I'll match subdomains with its' parent domain.

for example a.example.com and b.example.com are subdomains of example.com so on my new column which named parent_domain_id  I will set example.com's domain_id. (if domain is a top domain, it's parent_domain_id will be 0 )

I work with PHP and mysql and my machine has 8GB of RAM so I have some device limitations. Is there a trick about checking a huge data set row by row with PHP?

Comment: You should add a new column is_top_domain, you can populate it based on domain_name via a regex and then you can make the query easily

Comment: what about after finding top domains? @KA_lin

Comment: Determining what is a "top domain" is non-trivial. See [Mozilla's Public Suffix List](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Effective_TLD_List).

Comment: you want to find domain and subdomains of 'example.com' right?

Comment: `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` are subdomais of `example.com`. So their `parent_domain_id` must be `example.com`'s `domain_id` @KA_lin

Comment: MySQL is the wrong tool here. You need a hadoop cluster.

Comment: Get all subdomains of a certain domain:

    select * from domain where parent_domain_id in 
    (
        select id from domain where domain_name='example.com' LIMIT 1
    )

Comment: Problem is here. First I must find all subdomais then mathich (update) then select

Comment: why don't you clearly show the flow, in detail, in the question. Get your thoughts together, then publish it

Comment: if you reversed the domain names i.e. `com.example`, `com.exanple.a` then finding obviously related domain names may not be 'difficult'.? Mark these as processed then start tackling the more 'interesting' cases?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using PHP at all - and MySQL is pushing it too ... but let's run with it for the sake of brevity.  Why don't you take a look at stored procedures and see what you might be able to accomplish within MySQL itself: [Getting Started with MySQL Stored Procedures](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx)

Comment: write up the Hadoop solution, @Fuser97381

Comment: PHP should not be considered as part of the guts of the solution. It is the mechanism to call that which does the work here

Comment: thinking aloud: Would it be possible to use the `Domain Name System` directly to do the queries and obtain the information? Ok, it may be not as fast but it could be done incrementally. If you stored the results yourself then it would be more complete eventually. It may cost money to do that many queries against the DNS in a short space of time.

Comment: @RyanVincent tried to make a solution from your idea

Comment: Keep in mind that a domain might have `.co.uk` or similar, so your regex can't be based on splitting dots...

Comment: I think with `rpad(reverse)` a single scan should be sufficient. I do hope this 'conversion' is just a one-time-action, and all new inputs will be converted daily.

Comment: Now I have given code, only the requester can check if it works.

Comment: @Fuser97381 I really would love to see a Hadoop-Idea here. How would you manage data locality? If every row gets sent to the master node, you win nothing at all. I think you first have to solve most of the original problem before even filling a Hadoop-Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: for most domain names this should work.

You could get a sorted list which contains all the domains (up to a fixed length) ordered by domain and increasing length.

I would start with Comment of @RyanVincent.

```
select domain_id, domain_name, reverse(domain_name) as reversed
from domain
order by 
rpad(reverse(domain_name),130,' '),
length(domain_name),
reverse(domain_name), 
domain_id
```

Goal is to be able to get row by row ordered by length and then by alphabet.

Your example would give

```
        google.com -> moc.elgoog, 
      a.google.com -> moc.elgoog.a
   xy.a.google.com -> moc.elgoog.a.yx
      b.google.com -> moc.elgoog.a
```

In php:

```
  $currentDomains = array(); 
  /*
     array domainpart => id
     moc     => 0
     elgoog  => id of google.com as long as we are in subdomains of google.com
     a       => id of a.google.com as long as we are in subdomains of a.google.com

     this gets never longer then the number of domainparts, so usually a very
     short array!
   */

  $sql = "select domain_id, domain_name, reverse(domain_name) as reversed\n"
      . " from domain \n"
      . " order by  \n"
      . " rpad(reverse(domain_name),130,' '), \n"
      . " length(domain_name), \n"
      . " reverse(domain_name),  \n"
      . " domain_id"
      ;

  doSelect($sql);

  while($row = getRow()){
    $parts = preg_split('/\./', $row["reversed"]);
    # print("parts = \n");print_r($parts);
    $rid = $row["domain_id"];

    $matchedDomains = array();
    $parentId = $rid; // if no parent, show to yourself

    $i = 0;
    // 1. match identical parts
    //     php is funny, the array is a key=>value but with 
    //     foreach it restores the key-values in the inserted order.
    foreach($currentDomains as $name => $cid){
      # print("> check $i '$name' '{$parts[$i]}'\n");
      if($parts[$i] == $name){
        $matchedDomains[$name] = $cid;
        if($cid > 0){
          $parentId = $cid;
        }
        $i++;
      }
      else{
        break;
      }
    }
    // 2.
    // new parts
    while ($i < count($parts)-1){
      # print("> store '{$parts[$i]}' \n");
      $matchedDomains[$parts[$i]] = 0; // no row matches those
      $i++;
    }
    $matchedDomains[$parts[count($parts)-1]] = $rid;
    $currentDomains = $matchedDomains;
    print(" update domain set parent_id = $parentId where id = $rid\n"); // use PDO
  }
```

So google.com is its own parent domain, a.google.com has google.com as parent and so on.